# Apache: Serve all URLs on a domain with the index page, without rewriting path?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, url

I'm writing a Backbone.js application that makes use of the HTML5 history API. I would like users to be able to create URLs of the form:

```
domain.com/any
domain.com/random
domain.com/paththattheuserlikes
```

and have all these URLs routed to my `index.html` page, where the Backbone router will take the path and process the request appropriately.

My question is this: how can I set up Apache to route all requests to that domain to `index.html`, while keeping the path in place so that the Backbone router will handle the request correctly?

I know how to do a simple Apache redirect, but I'm worried that will remove the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Apache config file, put the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[/]?$ /index.html [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite all requests that are made up of alphanumeric characters to index.html, while still preserving the query string *and* still appearing as being from the same path as typed. Thus, if the user went to yourdoma.in/someoldpath, index.html would be displayed but the address bar would still say yourdoma.in/someoldpath.

As mentioned by the first poster, if you want to know which path was typed, you could change the second line above to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]?$ /index.html?pathtyped=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which would pass the original path typed to index.html in the "pathtyped" request variable.

Comment: Perfect - I can get the path as typed client-side using `window.location.pathname`, that is what counts. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lose the original paths, you need to include them (or a substitution) in the query string of the target page to be able to get and process them.